# how to find a known object in a picture using open cv in android

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I want to make a function like `boolean findobject(Mat ref_img,Mat object_img)`
which will return true if the ref_img contains the object_img otherwise false.
I am using SurfFeatureDetector to find out the object in the ref_img but I am not getting which parameter should I use to come to a conclusion.
thanks in advance.
I am using the following code
though it has a string return value I want to change it to bool .

```
String detect(Mat ref_img, Mat& output)
{
 //cvtColor(img, gray, CV_RGBA2GRAY); // Assuming RGBA input

//previous code
    /*
int minHessian = 400;
SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );
std :: vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;
detector.detect( ref_img, keypoints_1 );

//-- Draw keypoints
Mat img_keypoints_1;
drawKeypoints( ref_img, keypoints_1, img_keypoints_1, Scalar :: all( - 1), DrawMatchesFlags :: DEFAULT );
output = img_keypoints_1;
*/
String result="";
try{
int minHessian = 400;

SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );

std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object, keypoints_scene;

detector.detect( output, keypoints_object );
detector.detect( ref_img, keypoints_scene );

//-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;

extractor.compute( output, keypoints_object, descriptors_object );
extractor.compute( ref_img, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene );

//-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
std::vector< DMatch > matches;
matcher.match( descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches );

double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

//-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ )
{ double dist = matches[i].distance;
  if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
  if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
}

ostringstream os;
//os << max_dist;
//String s=os.str();
//result.append("max dist:");
//result.append(s);
//LOGI(s);//os.str());
//os<<min_dist;
//result.append("  min dist:");
//result.append(os.str());
//LOGI(os.str());
//printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist );
//printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist );

//-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++ )
{ if( matches[i].distance < 2*min_dist )
   { good_matches.push_back( matches[i]); }
}

Mat img_matches;
drawMatches( output, keypoints_object, ref_img, keypoints_scene,
             good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
             vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );

//-- Localize the object
std::vector<Point2f> obj;
std::vector<Point2f> scene;

os << good_matches.size();
result.append("no of good match:");
result.append(os.str());

for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
{
  //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
  obj.push_back( keypoints_object[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
  scene.push_back( keypoints_scene[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
}

Mat H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );

//-- Get the corners from the image_1 ( the object to be "detected" )
std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);
obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0,0); obj_corners[1] = cvPoint( output.cols, 0 );
obj_corners[2] = cvPoint( output.cols, output.rows ); obj_corners[3] = cvPoint( 0, output.rows );
std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);

perspectiveTransform( obj_corners, scene_corners, H);

//-- Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene - image_2 )
line( img_matches, scene_corners[0] + Point2f(output.cols, 0), scene_corners[1] + Point2f( output.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4 );
line( img_matches, scene_corners[1] + Point2f( output.cols, 0), scene_corners[2] + Point2f( output.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
line( img_matches, scene_corners[2] + Point2f( output.cols, 0), scene_corners[3] + Point2f( output.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );
line( img_matches, scene_corners[3] + Point2f( output.cols, 0), scene_corners[0] + Point2f( output.cols, 0), Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 4 );

//-- Show detected matches
//imshow( "Good Matches & Object detection", img_matches );

output = img_matches;
}
catch(Exception& e)
{
    result.append("exception occured");
}
return result;``
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what your function does is the following: It matches feature points between a reference image/object `ref_img` and another image (`output`) and then computes a 2d-homography between those two images. Then it maps the rectangular bounds of the reference image into the other image and draws them.

What you want is to decide whether the queried object is contained in the image or not. I'm not sure but I guess you could try to decide that based on the amount of maches that are found or on their distance.